# SSE2 instruction to convert a 8x16 register to two 4x32 registers having the even and odd indexed elements

Tags: c, x86, intrinsics, sse2

Is there any SSE2 instruction to convert a 8x16 register to two 4x32 registers,one 4x32 register having the odd indexed elements from the 8x16 register and the other having the even indexed elements? Please suggest.

Comment: You're gonna want to add the "x86" and "assembly" tags or the "c" and/or "c++" tags to clarify which you want it in. (assembly, or intrinsics)

Comment: Whether the operands are signed will make a difference, since you need to either zero-extend or sign-extend the data when copying to the new 4x32 format. Signed or unsigned?

Comment: The operands are signed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested:

```
movdqa xmm1, xmm0
pslld xmm0, 16
psrad xmm1, 16  ; odd words
psrad xmm0, 16  ; even words
```

Should be easy enough to convert to intrinsics.

There is no single instruction for this, not even in later versions of SSE. Multiple-outputs is very rare, mostly reserved for old instructions.

`pmovsxwd` from SSE4.1 uses the (for this problem) wrong subset of elements, namely the bottom 4.

Comment: If you’re going to do the operation on multiple vectors and are on SNB or IVB, it’s may be a small win to use PSHUFB instead of PSLLD, as it can use a different port than the shifts.  This is really getting way off into the weeds however, and your answer is excellent as is (and besides, PSLLD wins handily on older cores).

Comment: @StephenCanon interesting, I hadn't thought of that. Might be a little annoying to get the shuffle-mask in there, `palignr` would work too, right? Also goes to a different port on Sandy (where did you get a list for IVB?), and is less horribly slow than `pshufb` on Core2 65nm, advantages all around, I think

Comment: @harold: no port list for IVB, but it’s a “tock” of SNB, so the issue ports *should* be the same.

Comment: Thanks all for your response

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if there's a single instruction for this, but something like this ought to work (untested):

```
; Assume that the 8 16-bit values are in xmm0
PSHUFLW xmm1,xmm0,0D8h  ; Change word order to 3120 in the low qword
PSHUFHW xmm1,xmm1,0D8h  ; Change word order to 3120 in the high qword
PSHUFD xmm1,xmm1,0D8h   ; Change dword order to 3120
MOVAPD xmm0,xmm1        ; Copy to xmm0
PUNPCKLWD xmm0,xmm0     ; Expand even words to dwords
PUNPCKHWD xmm1,xmm1     ; Expand odd words to dwords
PSLLD xmm0,16           ; Sign-extend
PSRAD xmm0,16           ; ...
PSLLD xmm1,16
PSRAD xmm1,16
```

`xmm0` should now contain the 4 even words sign-extended to 32 bits, and `xmm1` should contain the odd words.

If you can use SSE4.1 instructions it's possible to simplify the sign-extension part a bit. For the even words (`xmm0`) you could replace the unpack and the two shifts with:

```
PMOVSXWD xmm0,xmm0
```

Comment: Shouldn't those be `psrad`?

Comment: Yes SSE4.1 instructions can be used.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the answer...Really appreciate your help :-)